# SwiftUI : Why format a TextField for currency in EUR set symbol on the left

Tags: swift, swiftui, format, textfield, formatter

I try to use a TextField with user locale currency format

I try this

```
struct MyView: View {
        @State private var amount = 0.0
        
        let currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            formatter.locale = Locale.current
            return formatter
        }()
        
        var body: some View {
            Form {
                // Test 1
                TextField("Amount", value: $amount,
                          formatter: currencyFormatter)
                
                // Test 2
                TextField("Amount", value: $amount,
                          format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? ""))
        }
    }
```

Both TextField produce the same formatting error :

> Amount : €0,00

Expected:

> Amount : 0,00 €

For USD it works fine:

> Amount : $0.00

Comment: Why do you expect the currency to be on the right hand side of the amount? `€ 0,00` is the correct formatting.

Comment: What's `Locale.current`? In French, I'd expect the `€` after the amount, but in the US, I'd expect the `$` before. But is it the case in the US for euros?

Comment: Sorry but in France we write 0,00 € not €0,00

Comment: For instance, I saw on a few "US" website, that they write "€1.0", as it seems to be how they write currency amounts. So the locale is used. And if that's the "rule", then seeing "€0,00" if your local is US, it's normal, no?

Comment: This might be a bug that needs to be addressed by Apple since it is an issue with built in localization.

Comment: Weird. When I set the `locale` of the formatter explicitly to `Locale(identifier: "FR_fr")` it works.

Comment: @Larme thank for your help. I t helps me to found solution

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution by adding this to my code:

```
 Text("Transaction: \(Locale.current.identifier)" )
```

It render "en_FR"

So in my "project info" I just had "French localization" and know both TextField (Test 1 and Test 2) works fine!

[image: Project]

I also had Localizable string file to my project.

Please note a signing difference between Test 1 and Test 2:
in Test 1 the user must type the € sign in Test 2 user just have to a value. Make your own test and take the most valuable solution.

Comment: As we said in Apple world: "it's not a bug it's a feature". Real apple fan can understand this joke :)